# Vim weird indentation for .php

Tags: php, vim

I want to like this behavior of vim indentation.

```
public function foo()
{
    _ <= cursor position
}
```

But, it becomes way...

```
public function foo()
{
    _
    }
```

My .vimrc is

```
filetype plugin indent on

set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=0
set shiftwidth=4
set autoindent
set smartindent

autocmd FileType php setlocal sw=4 sts=4 ts=4 et
au BufRead,BufNewFile,BufReadPre *.php setl ft=php

inoremap {<Enter> {}<Left><CR><ESC><S-o>
inoremap [<Enter> []<Left><CR><ESC><S-o>
inoremap (<Enter> ()<Left><CR><ESC><S-o>
```

And whole is [here](https://github.com/akihiroyajima/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc).

Any ideas on what this might be?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belong on the Vim SE site which is located [here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Script47 : but which question about Vim is then not off-topic (it's a sincere question, that i already was wondering about)? --> This question deals about setting up `.vimrc`, which is written in [VimL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/viml/info) scripting language. So why should it be off-topic?

Comment: You probably want `filetype plugin indent on` inside your vimrc. It probably isn't necessary to have `autoindent` and `smartindent` if since the filetype indent script should handle it. (It also means you don't need `setl ft=php` autocmd).

Comment: @FDinoff In addition, `filetype plugin indent on` has already been added in the `.vimrc`.

Comment: @FDinoff Syntax does not work without `ft=php`...

Comment: @Script47 Thank you for your pointing out. It will be a reference when I want to question the next time.

Comment: @AkihiroYajima Syntax should happen automatically since vim has code that will set php files to filetype php. (Assume `filetype plugin indent on` is in the file.)

Answer (score 0):

It behaves like this because if you cut the line with `<Left><CR>`, vim will not take the end of the line (`"}"` in your case) in consideration for indenting.

Try this mapping instead:

```
inoremap {<Enter> {<cr>}<esc>O
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I tried it but it didn't work... I got the same result.